# Magento 2 Database Maintenance

Tags: database, magento2.2.2

I'm wondering which tables can be truncated in Magento 2 to stop the database from increasing in size?

I also have a table called 'customer_visitor' which is sitting at 1025058 rows and I'm wondering if this is the new session save path and if it can be truncated?

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it is for magento 1, does this still apply to 2 as I can see some of the log rows still exist in the magento 2 database?

Comment: Yes..it also applies on M2